# Прямая речь или нет? (2)

Tags: прямая-речь

**А я, думаешь, знаю, что ты там делаешь? Отвечаю: «Я не знаю».**

Такое чувство, что здесь нет прямой речи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А я, думаешь, знаю, что ты там делаешь? Отвечаю: я не знаю.**

В этом случае лучше использовать БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение) с изъяснительным значением. Тогда текст нормально смотрится.

Примеры:

**Отвечаю:** надо действовать так, как диктует право. [Светлана Сухова.  «Итоги», 2003.03.04]

**На это я отвечаю:** мы шьём то, что, сами надеваем, и не по праздникам, а каждый день. [Народный костюм: архаика или современность? // «Народное творчество», 2004]

Но на один вопрос **я отвечаю:** солдаты не восстанут. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)]

**Отвечаю:** я и не жалуюсь, просто рассказываю...

Answer (score 3):

Типичная прямая речь. Вы дословно передаете свои слова.

**Отвечаю: "Я не знаю".**

Впрочем, я игнорировал первое предложение, так как с ним ничего не понятно.

Comment: Гм... М_Г, а почему Вы при последней корректировке точку после прямой речи убрали?

Comment: @slava1947 Сам не знаю, как это получилось. Спасибо, я вернул точку.

Comment: @slava1947 А Ваше "Гм... М_Г" (с перестановкой букв) я оценил, хотя не сразу заметил :)).

Comment: @slava1947 Я понял, как пропало изменение, сделанное Галиной. Может, эта история послужит кому-нибудь уроком. Я и она редактировали текст параллельно, и мой вариант был сохранен, а ее — нет. При этом появлялось предупреждение о том, что чьи-то изменения будут потеряны, но я его игнорировал.